# If I import my module, my services aren't singleton, but if I don't, my controllers don't work

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I've set up my project as follows:

- app

  - app.module (`imports: []`)
  - shared

    - shared.module (`declarations: [sharedComponent], providers: [sharedService]`)
    - sharedService
    - sharedComponent
  - module1

    - module1.module (`imports: [sharedModule]`)
    - module1.component (routing child uses sharedComponent)
  - module2

    - module2.module (`imports: [sharedModule]`)
    - module2.component (routing child uses sharedComponent)

This doesn't throw any errors, but setting a breakpoint in the `sharedService` constructor reveals that it's not singleton.

---

I can change my imports to this instead:

- app

  - app.module (`imports: [sharedModule]`)
  - shared

    - shared.module (`declarations: [sharedComponent], providers: [sharedService]`)
    - sharedService
    - sharedComponent
  - module1

    - module1.module (`imports: []`)
    - module1.component (routing child uses sharedComponent)
  - module2

    - module2.module (`imports: []`)
    - module2.component (routing child uses sharedComponent)

`sharedService` appears to be singleton now, but I get an error

> Component sharedComponentis not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

I want my shared services to be singleton, but need access to shared components. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to make `shared` a `provider` instead of a `module`.

Comment: Could you show us your `sharedModule`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else that runs across this issue, I had a core misunderstanding of what my shared module should contain. [The docs say](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-kinds-of-modules-should-i-have-and-how-should-i-use-them):

> Create a **SharedModule** with the **components, directives, and pipes** that
>   you use everywhere in your app. This module should consist entirely of
>   declarations, most of them exported.
>
> The SharedModule may re-export other widget modules, such as
>   CommonModule, FormsModule, and modules with the UI controls that you
>   use most widely.
>
> **The SharedModule should not have providers** for reasons explained
>   previously. Nor should any of its imported or re-exported modules have
>   providers. If you deviate from this guideline, know what you're doing
>   and why.
>
> Import the SharedModule in your feature modules, both those loaded
>   when the app starts and those you lazy load later.
>
> Create a **CoreModule** with **providers for the singleton services** you load
>   when the application starts.
>
> Import CoreModule in the root AppModule only. Never import CoreModule
>   in any other module.
>
> Consider making CoreModule a pure services module with no
>   declarations.

Moving my shared services out of SharedModule and into CoreModule is the solution.

Comment: As of Angular 6, we now have a `providedIn` property that enables tree-shaking on the service. We no longer need to define services in the `providers` array of the module rendering this question/answer somewhat moot.